# an example of two non-commuting projection operators.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Give an example of two non-commuting projection operators in $\mathbb R^2.$
I know in $\mathbb R^2 f(x,y)=(0,y)$ and $ g(x,y)=(x,0)$ and $h(x,y)=(x,y)$ are projection but are not commuting.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: An example of two non-commuting projection operators in R^2.

Answer (score 1):

Your Projector $h$ is the identity, so it commute with any other transformation.

For the products of $f$ and $g$ you have $fg(x,y)=(0,0)=gf(x,y)$ so also those projectors commute.

As an example of a projection that does not commute with $f$ and $g$ we can have: $k(x,y)=(x,x)$.