# An example of two non-commuting projections

Tags: functional-analysis

Exercise 8 at page 40 of Conway's FA asks to give an example of two non-commuting projections. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157671/an-example-of-two-non-commuting-projection-operators) there is an answer but even though $k^2=k$ holds but $\operatorname{ker}(P) \ne {\operatorname{ran}(P)}^{\perp}$. Am I wrong or is there a correct simple counter-example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in saying that your linked example is not a projection in the sense that Conway's FA defines projections; it is a "non-orthogonal" or "oblique" projection.

As an example of non-commuting orthogonal projections, consider $f(x,y) = (x,0)$ and $g(x,y) = \frac 1{2}(x+y,x+y)$. That is, the transformations over $\Bbb R^2$ whose matrices are
$$
\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad \frac 12 \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}.
$$

Comment: ker g = {(x,-x) | x \in R}. ran g = R. How can I calculate (ran g)^{\perp} to check if ker g = (ran g)^{\perp}?

Comment: @Magic It is not true that $\operatorname{ran}(g) = \Bbb R$. We have $\operatorname{ran}(g) = \{(x,x)\mid  x\in \Bbb R\}$.